# Databricks Data Type Conversion error double to decimal

Tags: types, azure-databricks, date-conversion

In databricks while writing data to curated layer, see error - Failed to execute user defined function (Double => decimal(38,18)). Does anyone know if faced such issue and how to resolve it.

When we multiply 2 numbers; the result size could go to the tune of 2x (num1 size + num2 size). Before we are explicitly casting multiplication of these 2, the result is bigger than to be casted data type. Its something like (double (x,y) can't be converted to decimal (x,y-1)). If we decrease the data type size of the values to me multiplied before multiplication we are getting incorrect value due to precision loss.

Comment: provide more information - what databricks runtime version, show sample of code, etc.

Comment: Apache Spark 2.4.5, dont have sample code as it happens with the kind of data result of 2 double is greater than decimal(38,18)